# How to render solid elements in Three.js using JSONLoader?

Tags: three.js

I can render shell elements through JSONLoader. Is it possible to render solid element (Tetra, Hexa, etc.,) through Three.js' JSONLoader?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add some of your code, or better explain your problem, so we can you.

Comment: Actually I am using the code which is in the example.          loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( 'file.js', function ( geometry ) {
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( ) );
    scene.add( mesh );
} );

Comment: Any errors ? Also, `MeshFaceMaterial` is supposed to hold nested materials I think. Did you tried with easier ones, like `MeshBasicMaterial` ?

Comment: Hi gman, Thanks for your swift reply. Actually, my JSON starts with 3 in faces information. "faces":
[3,0,42,61,1,0,
3,42,43,62,61,0,
3,43,44,63,62,0, etc] The requirement is how to render a solid element. So which format is easy to render solids? Thanks in advance

Comment: just use `MeshBasicMaterial` to have a basic rendering